# How to pass request context to GRPC Go endpoints from Ruby

Tags: ruby, go, grpc, grpc-go, grpc-ruby

I'm calling GRPC endpoints from Ruby.

The proto endpoints are for example `rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply)`, and implemented in Go, so they take context when calling from Go. The generated client supports `client.SayHello(ctx context.Context, request *HelloRequest)`.

However when calling from Ruby it's just `client.SayHello(request)`, where `request`'s type is HelloRequest. How do I pass in the context? I want to do this because the Go endpoint implementations use the context in a variety of ways such as logging.

Comment: The `Context` is created when a request is received in the go app. You shouldn't be sending a request context. The handler(endpoint) must create its own [context](https://pkg.go.dev/context).

Comment: It seems that you want to pass some non-request-values ​​into the grpc request. It is actually a problem of the grpc protocol. The grpc request contains not only a request body, but also a request header, which in golang is https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.46.0/metadata#MD
I am not sure whether this request header can be used in ruby's grpc library, and how to use it.

Comment: The overall process should be that ruby ​​adds some additional parameters such as log-id into the grpc request header when requesting, then golang can get this parameters from grpc request header by `Interceptor` https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc#UnaryServerInterceptor . And then store it in the context.Context. Hopes that can be helpful.